# Avoiding loops while accessing pixel information of an image

Tags: java, for-loop, arrays

I'm trying to copy the RGB values of an image to a 2D array. At the moment I'm using two nested for loops. My question is, is it possible to use `arraycopy` or any other method to make the operation faster?

The below code works fine, I just would like to optimize it.

```
private LSHColor[][] pixels = new LSHColor[w][h];
public LSHImage(BufferedImage img) {
    pixels = new LSHColor[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];
    for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
            pixels[x][y] = LSHColor.fromRGB(img.getRGB(x, y));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`arraycopy` is not going to help for two reasons. First reason is that you are not making a copy: you are creating an array based on the content of another array. On top of that, your `pixels[][]` is in column-major order, meaning that pixels of the same column are next to each other in memory, while images are stored in row-major order.

One thing that you can optimize is getting your pixels from the image. Rather than reading them one at a time, you can get them all at once, and then use your loops for processing, like this:

```
public LSHImage(BufferedImage img) {
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    pixels = new LSHColor[w][h];
    int[] raw = img.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);
    for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
            pixels[x][y] = LSHColor.fromRGB(raw[w*y+x]);
}
```

This makes a single call to `getRGB` instead of making `Width*Height` calls. Tradeoff here is that you use some temporary memory for the image, which may be prohibitive for larger images.